# Following Microsoft tutorial to build POSt request but doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

I am building a WebAPI using a Microsoft tutorial. They have this code to build a POST request to add an item to the database:

```
// POST: api/TodoItems
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
{
    _context.TodoItems.Add(todoItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    //return CreatedAtAction("GetTodoItem", new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
}
```

I have this code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public int PostItem([FromBody] Item item)
        {
            collection.addItem(item);
            return collection.getSize()
        }
    }
```

Here is my collection class and the method I am calling:

```
public class Items
{
    public Items()
    {}
    

    public ArrayList itemCollection = new ArrayList();

    public int getSize()
    {
        return itemCollection.Count;
    } 
    
    public string getItems()
    {
        
        foreach (var item in itemCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());        
        }
        return "";
    }
```

For now I am just saving items to an arraylist as I dont require a database yet. However, when I call my `getItems()` method it does not add it to the array and instead adds this:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  0 False
```

This should instead add a random Guid, the price and a boolean which should be true from my item class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(){}
    public Item(string Name, double Price, bool GlutenFree)
    {
        this.itemID = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.name = Name;
        this.price = Price;
        this.glutenFree = GlutenFree;
    }

    public Guid itemID;
    public string name;
    public double price;
    public bool glutenFree;
```

I don't understand why this is not picking up the data from my POST request which is just:

```
{"name":"pizza",
"price":10,
"glutenFree":false
}
```

Its the exact same as the Microsoft one so I'm not sure why its going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should actualy follow Pascal case convention while defining  properties in C# classes. Try converting the variables declared in item class to properites as below and check again, it should work. While defining properties you should always follow Pascal naming convention

```
public Guid itemID {get; set;} 
public string Name {get; set;}
public double Price {get; set;}
public bool GlutenFree {get; set;}
```

Comment: made those changes but it didnt make a difference, still getting the same error